# Valid alternatives of AbsoluteLayout

Tags: android

I'm updating an application where the user should be able to drag and drop some elements (buttons/imagebuttons) so that they change position, and I also need to get their X,Y coordinates.

In the previous versions I used `AbsoluteLayout`, even if deprecated. What could I use instead of it? Is there a real substitute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a fan of `RelativeLayout` combined with `LinearLayout`; but it is all about your particular use cases.

Comment: Is there any example of how to use them to reach my goals?

Comment: After some research I've found and used this http://www.tutorialeshtml5.com/2012/12/tutorial-android-drag-and-drop.html

Answer (score 0):

> What could I use instead of it?

Your own custom `ViewGroup`, that knows your business rules and that you control. Whether you create it completely from scratch, or you fork `AbsoluteLayout` and maintain your own fork, is up to you.

Comment: Is there any library to do layouts with draggable elements or similar stuff? I don't think to be able to create my own viewgroup or editing absolutelayout, I'm still a newbie.

Comment: @Vektor88: There are plenty of libraries that use touch events. I am not aware of one that is designed for arbitrary dragging of arbitrary widgets inside a container, though.